# How to assign the content of a jquery variable to another variable

Tags: jquery, css

I attempting to assign the content of a variable to another variable. How do I do this?
So far I have tried this:

```
var className = $($(this).attr("class"););

$('.content').html(className)
```

EDIT:

Please assume the end value for "var className = $($(this).attr("class"););" is point1

point 1 contains:

EDIT 2: (CONTAINS FULL CODE)

```
    <div class="content"><h1>testing hello world</h1><div class="position"> <div class="point1"> test<br> awewa<br> TEST <h1> test </h1> </div></div></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var point1 = '<div class="content"><h1>testing hello world</h1><div class="position"> <div class="point1"> test<br> awewa<br> TEST <h1> test </h1> </div></div></div>';
    var className = "Broken";
    $('.content [class] [class]').click(function () {$(this).fadeTo(250, 0.25, function () {
    className = $(this).attr("class");
    $('.content').html(className)

    $(this).fadeTo(250, 1.00);

    });}
    );

    </script> 


var point1 = '<div class="content"><h1>testing hello world</h1><div class="position"> <div class="point1"> test<br> awewa<br> TEST <h1> test </h1> </div></div></div>';
```

"$('.content').html(className)" < className of this needs to contain the string in point1)

Comment: DO you want to set the class of one element as another element's text?

Comment: What I am doing is this: I am writing variables for a bunch of classes. These classes will contain new HTML. So when you click a class "var className = $($(this).attr("class"););" grabs variable containing the new content and $('.content').html(className) inserts that variables content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK assuming i understood clearly. You have some html stored in some variables that are same as class names of some element and on click of that element. You want to ge the html from that variable and assign as content to another element with classname `.content`.

```
$('.someClass').on('click',function(){
    var className = this.className; // Get the classname whic is a variable
   var content = window[className];
   if(content)
    $('.content').html(content); //Assuming variable is defined in the window Scope. 
});
```

Splitting this:-

`window[className]` <-- to get the variable defined in the window scope.

#### Update:-

Try this based on your code update. Since you are replacing the content and the click to happen again you should go with delegated  event handler using `.on()`, use `.live` for older version of jquery.

```
   var className = "Broken";
   $(document).on('click', '.content [class] [class]', function () {
       $(this).fadeTo(250, 0.25, function () {
           className = this.className;
           $('.content').html(window[className]);
           $(this).fadeTo(250, 1.00);

       });
   });
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Zpyq/)

Comment: This does what I want it to do but it only works once. I click the class and even if the new content contains another class and variable it wont work.

Comment: Is the Demo Fiddle working for you? Can you prepare a demo fiddle?

Comment: Which version of jquery you are using?

Comment: Alright. So you click the first class, but it next menu when you click a class it goes to a blank screen

Comment: So it should work. Are you able to replicate the issue in my fiddle?

Comment: Make sure you assign the variables in window scope use  `window.point1` etc or remove var from variable declaration as in the demo

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**:

It sounds like this is what you're trying to do

```
var className = $('.' + $(this).attr("class")).html();
$('.content').html(className);
```

Comment: What I am doing is this: I am writing variables for a bunch of classes. These classes will contain new HTML. So when you click a class "var className = $($(this).attr("class"););" grabs variable containing the new content and $('.content').html(className) inserts that variables content.

Comment: @sephiith There are no jQuery variables with that syntax. You probably should be using jQuery's `.data()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'this' represented a element (like if you are inside a $.each() callback then $(this).attr('class') will return all of the CSS classes assigned to that element. This is not the same as all the CSS rules that effect it only the value that appears in the 'class=""'. The outer $() that you have will hide the return value from that first assigment in your question. The second line will set the innerHTML of an element with the class "content" to the value that the first line returned.

Comment: "$('.content').html(className)" 

className will contain the name of a variable. I need to insert the content of that variable into that position. (as it contains HTML)

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntactical error in the code other than that it looks fine.

Assuming what you want to do is to display the value of class property of the element `this` in `.content` element

```
var className = $(this).attr("class");
$('.content').html(className)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gHDSA/)

Update:
Assuming the `className` is the name of a property associated with an object `x` then you can use `x[className ]` to fetch the value.
If the variable is created in the global context then you can use `window[className]` to fetch the value

```
var point1 = '<div class="content"><h1>testing hello world</h1><div class="position"> <div class="point1"> test<br> awewa<br> TEST <h1> test </h1> </div></div></div>';
jQuery(function($){
    var className = "Broken";
    $('.content').on('click', '[class] [class]', function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(250, 0.25, function () {
            className = $(this).attr("class");
            $('.content').html(window[className])
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gHDSA/2/)

Comment: After this: "var className = $(this).attr("class");" The value will be point1

point1 references a preconfigured variable in my jquery. I need the string in that preconfigured variable to be in place of className in the below line:

$('.content').html(className)

Comment: @sephiith Can you share how the variable is defined

Comment: The above code returns: point1 in the .content class. It needs to be the content in the point1 variable.

Comment: @sephiith in that case you can use `$('.content').html(window[className])`

Comment: This works, but it only works once. When it updates the .content class with the new content the classes in that don't react to the jquery